# Javascript get html from external site

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsonp

I don't know if this is possible or allowed, but basically I want to go to http://www.nfl.com/scores and get the scores for a particular week. It seems like each game has a certain class and I could the scores and team easily if I can access their html. I think I need to use AJAX or JSON or some combination. Thanks!

UPDATE:

proxy.php

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
            $url = "http://www.nfl.com/scores/2012/PRE1http://www.nfl.com/scores/2012/PRE1";
            $htm = file_get_contents($url);
            echo $htm;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

nflScores.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.get("proxy.php", function(response) { 
    alert(response) });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems that my alert box is filled with tons of html. Can I use some sort of .getElementByID() method to find certain elements?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Javascript read the source of any web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680562/can-javascript-read-the-source-of-any-web-page) and [Javascript or JQuery get html content from external site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788758/javascript-or-jquery-get-html-content-from-external-site) and potentially others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your server-side (PHP?) script, download nhl.com site, parse html, send to javascript using json or print it directly on your website.

However, i think nfl.com won't be happy about it.

Comment: this seems doable. Can you elaborate or maybe give an example?

Comment: [This is good start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409264/how-to-parse-actual-html-from-page-using-curl)

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible due to XHR's [same-origin policy.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Check if NFL has an API you can use to get the scores. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57106/anyone-know-of-an-nfl-or-nba-api). Doesn't look like they have an API released, but you may be able to gather the information anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Either way, the laws around "screen scraping" are pretty grey.